# A javascript selector that matches on class, excluding others

Tags: javascript, css, sizzle

I am trying to write a selector for querySelector that will include the divs of class "foo" but not "foo bar". I'm not using jQuery in this project.

```
<div class="foo">include me</div>
<div class="foo">and me</div>
<div class="foo bar">not me</div>
```

I have tried playing with [:not()](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation) but am unsure of the correct syntax as this doesn't work for me

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.foo|*:not(.bar)');
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.foo:not(.bar)');
```

This will select all `div` elements having `class` `.foo` and not `.foo` with `.bar`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zgu5ucyv/) (Check the console for output)

Comment: Ah, so close... thanks =)

Comment: @Richard np, you welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.foo:not(.bar)');
```